# Is copywriting allowed according to halacha

Tags: employment, business, sheker-false, lifnei-iver, genaivas-daas

Is it allowed (or not allowed) according to halacha to do [copywriting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copywriting)? That means you use certain words and write a certain way that makes people more likely to buy a product for example. You are not nessecarily lying but you are [nudging](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nudge_theory) people to buy your product or service.

This is relevant in marketing activities such as [lead generation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead_generation) were you write texts to (or for) potential customers to buy your product.

Comment: There's a lot to say about this. Please see this helpful answer, including the sources mentioned there: https://dinonline.org/2022/06/15/marketing-question/

Comment: @Shmuel thank you thats a usefull article.